# Display a list of html <detail> tags as a stable grid

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have a list of html detail tags that I want to display in grid form. The issue I am having is that if I expand some of these tags, it re-positions some of the other ones.

Here is my code:

```
function setBody(){  
  var selDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var form = document.getElementById("inputform");

  createCheckboxes(selDiv);
  document.getElementById("inputform").style.margin = "40px";
  selDiv.style.height = "500px";
  selDiv.style.width = "100%";
  selDiv.style.marginTop = "10px";
  selDiv.style.left = "50px";
  selDiv.style.position = "relative";
  selDiv.style.left = "0px";
  selDiv.style.display = "grid";
  form.insertBefore(selDiv,form.childNodes[0]);
}

function createCheckboxes(selDiv)
{
  var ulExp = document.createElement("ul");
  ulExp.style.width = "100%";
  for (var key in contacts)
  {
    var expDiv = document.createElement("div");
    expDiv.style.display = "grid";
    expDiv.style.float = "left";

    var liExp = document.createElement("li");
    liExp.style.width = "270px";
    liExp.style.float = "left";
    liExp.style.display = "inline";

    var sum = document.createElement('summary');
    sum.innerHTML = key;

    var expBlk = document.createElement('details');
    expBlk.appendChild(sum);
    expBlk.style.float = "left";
    expBlk.style.margin = "5px";
    expBlk.style.paddingLeft = "10px";
    expBlk.style.width = "250px";

    if (contacts.hasOwnProperty(key))
    {
      var ulChk = document.createElement("ul");
      ulChk.style.float = "left";
      ulChk.style.display = "inline-block";

      var persons = contacts[key];
      
      for (var i=0; i < persons.length; i++)
      {
        var br = document.createElement("br");  
        var description = document.createTextNode(persons[i]    ["givenName"]+" "+persons[i]["sn"]);

        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.style.padding = "1px";

        var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.name = persons[i]["uids"];
        checkbox.value = persons[i]["sn"];

        label.appendChild(checkbox);
        label.appendChild(description);
        ulChk.appendChild(label);
        ulChk.appendChild(br);
        expBlk.appendChild(ulChk);
        liExp.appendChild(expBlk);
        expDiv.appendChild(liExp);
      }
      selDiv.appendChild(expDiv);
    }
  }
}
```

The unexpanded version:
    [image: Unexpanded]
One expanded version:
    [image]
Another expanded version:
    [image]

I do not want these gaps showing up. I would rather just have the blocks below the opened block to move vertically downward. Is there a way to do that using Javascript? This is my first JS code, and I have never done JQuery or almost any other web languages, so ideally I would prefer a JS solution, if there is any. Thanks.

Comment: then wrap what you want to be on a single line in a div tag

Comment: use some grid layout, or seperate your items in specific divs... If all of them are floating in same container, then they will move inside the container. If you keep them in seperated containers, they will stay together and move down when expanded...

Comment: If I understand you guys right, I will have to make vertical divs and loop through to distribute departments in each div evenly?